# StringUtils or any library class method to preserve the delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string "role1@role2@role3@role4$arole" separated with delimiter @ and $. I used below java code

```
String str = "role1@role2@role3@role4$arole";
        String[] values = StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(str, "\\@\\$");

        for (String value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

And got the result

```
role1
role2
role3
role4
arole
```

But my requirement is to preserve the delimiter in the result. So, the result has to be as per requirement

```
role1
@role2
@role3
@role4
$arole
```

I analyzed the apache commons StringUtils method to do that but was unable to found any clue.

Any library class to get the above intended results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a simple `split` with a positive lookahead:

```
String str = "role1@role2@role3@role4$arole";
String[] res = str.split("(?=[@$])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
// => [role1, @role2, @role3, @role4, $arole]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/1tzTR9)

The `(?=[@$])` regex matches any *location* in a string that is followed with a `@` or `$` symbol (note the `$` does not have to be escaped inside a `[...]` character class).